# Renaming All Files in a Directory

Tags: linux

I split a large text file into 60 chunks, which are are named xaa, xab, xac,...xcg. I want to rename these files so that they all end with .txt

How can I do this from the linux command line?

Looked in the split command for the ability to customize the filenames. Looked on Stack Overflow for other solutions but the ones I've come across are all too specific to the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your shell is the default Bash:

```sh
for f in x??; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done
```

If you want to be more specific, you could say `x[abc][a-z]` instead of `x??`.

This is good enough for a one-liner. In a script you would want to check that `"$f"` exists before trying to rename it.

Comment: This assumes there are no existing .txt files.